# Select two best classifier using F1-score,Recall and precision

Tags: machine-learning, python, classification

I have three classifiers that classify same dataset with these results:

```
classifier A:
              precision    recall   f1-score 
  micro avg       0.36      0.36      0.36      
  macro avg       0.38      0.43      0.36       
  weighted avg    0.36      0.36      0.32    

classifier B:
              precision    recall   f1-score 
   micro avg       0.55      0.55      0.55      
   macro avg       0.60      0.60      0.56       
   weighted avg    0.61      0.55      0.53       

classifier C:
               precision    recall   f1-score 
   micro avg       0.34      0.34      0.34       
   macro avg       0.36      0.38      0.32      
   weighted avg    0.39      0.34      0.32
```

I want two select two best of them, and I know F1-score is a parameter for compare the classifiers because of its harmony between precision and recall.
So, at first I select classifier B for its best F1-score. for next, both A and C have a same F1-measure,
I want to ask how can I select between them?

Comment: [Why is accuracy not the best measure for assessing classification models?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312780/1352) Everything in that thread applies equally to F1, recall and precision. See also [Classification probability threshold](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312119/1352).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

f1-score combines precision and recall in a single figure. As both are pretty similar in A and C cases, f1-score is similar too.

Your choice depends on what it is less harmful in your categorization: false positives or false negatives.

I do recommend you to read the 3rd chapter of ["DEEP LEARNING:From Basics to Practice" volume 1 by Andrew Glassner](https://www.glassner.com/portfolio/deep-learning-from-basics-to-practice/). There you have the three concepts (precision, recall and f1-score) described in a very illustrative way.

Comment: they are not comparable if we dont have FP or FN?

Comment: You do not need direct access to FN or FN values. Precision and recall only varies in a part of their fraction formulas which includes FN or FP, so your displayed values reflect their relationship. What [Nga Dao](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/users/42821/nga-dao) and I mean is that your choice depends on the impact of false positives or false negatives in your system. [Nga Dao](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/users/42821/nga-dao) example is quite nice.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your application. Assume that you design a classifier model to predict whether a person has cancer. If you wanna say confidently that a person has cancer, you probably prefer a classifier with high precision.
On the other hand, if you want to make sure all people with cancer will be caught, you probably prefer a classifier with high recall.